# Jstree in laravel

Tags: laravel, jstree

I am newbie to jsTree, I want to use it in my Laravel project.I have department and user table .A department has many users.A user belongs to one department.This is the foreach loop that i tried to show users and departments,but its not with jstree.I coudn't find any information that could help me with this in Laravel.I would appreciate a lot if someone could help me with some information about this.Thanks in advance

```
                    @foreach($employees as $employee)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $employee->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{  $employee->department->name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

department.php

```
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);
    }
```

employee.php

```
    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
    }
```

Comment: JSTree is a `JavaScript` plugin that requires a specific data structure to work. You need to have an AJAX route that fetches your data and structures it as required, then returns it in JSON format. Have an `@foreach()` element that outputs PHP does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: AJAX is a method for performing `GET` (and `POST`, etc) requests from JavaScript, which is where JSTree lives. You give it a route, that route is handled by a `Controller` and returns data for JSTree. JSTree can handle the create/edit/delete aspects, but that's a bit more complicated...

Comment: I needed it only for displaying the departments as nodes and when i click on them to display  the users /employees.I have done the edit delete part but not with jstree  .You helped me a lot,thank you!

Comment: No problem! Sorry I couldn't provide a more concrete answer, but it's a bit too broad of a question for Stackoverflow currently. I think the documentation is pretty decent for explaining how to use JSTree effectively, but if you're unfamiliar with the terminology, it can be difficult. Keep working with it, and if you have a more specific issue, feel free to edit this/open a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.I will learn it more and practice it!